# Full proto too large to save, cleared variables

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I got this error while rendering google app engine code.

Do any body have knowledge about this error?

Comment: Please paste the error and tell us more specifically what triggered it, and show us code if possible.

Comment: Plus, you might hit some limits of GAE according the title

Answer (score 10):

Are you using appstats? It looks like this can happen when appstats is recording state about your app, especially if you're storing lots of data on the stack. It isn't harmful, but you won't be able to see everything when inspecting calls in appstats.

Comment: This comes from Appstats and just means that Appstats has recorded more data than it can fit in 1 MB (the limit for an Appstats record).  The error is harmless, but you will get less useful output from the Appstats UI -- in particular, it will not show the values of local variables when you open up a stack frame.