# How to add memcache or otherwise improve latency?

Tags: python, performance, google-app-engine, memcached

According to webpagetest.org, my 2 pages have very different latency, so it seems that on one page memcache speeds it up or what is otherwise the reason for that page 2 is so slow when I'v tried to use memcache and even turned off images and turned off javascript and page 2 is still slow? Why is the time to first byte so slow at the list page when I use memcache?

[image]
[image]

The code that is slow is what I should profile but when it's debugged it says it goes through the whole function fast and fetches from memcache:

```
2013-12-24 14:12:27.426 /india 200 12919ms 16kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36 module=default version=2014c
I 2013-12-24 14:12:14.573 got India data from memcache
D 2013-12-24 14:12:14.576 attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region 0 city 0
D 2013-12-24 14:12:14.577 got data 10381 from memcache
D 2013-12-24 14:12:14.577 attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region 0 city 0
D 2013-12-24 14:12:14.579 got data 930 from memcache
D 2013-12-24 14:12:14.579 attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region 0 city 0
D 2013-12-24 14:12:14.580 got data 817 from memcache
D 2013-12-24 14:12:14.580 attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region 0 city 0
D 2013-12-24 14:12:14.581 got data 455 from memcache
D 2013-12-24 14:12:14.582 attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region 0 city 0
D 2013-12-24 14:12:14.583 got data 137 from memcache
D 2013-12-24 14:12:14.583 attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region 0 city 0
D 2013-12-24 14:12:14.584 got data 175 from memcache
```

The memcache helper functions are:

```
    def get_jobs_count(self, region, city):
        logging.debug('attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region %s city %s'
                       % (str(region), str(city)))
        key = str(region) + 'jobscount' + str(city)
        data = memcache.get(key)
        jobs_count = None
        if data is not None:
            logging.debug('got data %s from memcache', str(data))
            return data
        else:
            if city and int(city) > 0:
                logging.debug('fetching number of ads for city %s',
                              str(city))
                jobs_count_gql = \
                    db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Ad WHERE category IN ('6010', '6020', '6030', '6040', '6090') AND cities = KEY('City', :1) AND published = True AND modified > :2 "
                                , city, datetime.now()
                                - timedelta(days=609))
                jobs_count = jobs_count_gql.count(limit=40000)
            elif region and int(region) > 0:
                logging.debug('fetching number of ads for region %s',
                              str(region))
                jobs_count_gql = \
                    db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Ad WHERE category IN ('6010', '6020', '6030', '6040', '6090') AND regions = KEY('Region', :1) AND published = True AND modified > :2"
                                , int(region), datetime.now()
                                - timedelta(days=609))

                # jobs_count_gql = db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Ad WHERE category IN ('6010', '6020', '6030', '6040', '6090') AND regions = KEY('Region', :1) AND published = True AND modified > :2 ",region, datetime.now() - timedelta(days=609))

                jobs_count = jobs_count_gql.count(limit=40000)
            #logging.debug('adding count %d to memcache', jobs_count)
            memcache.add(key, jobs_count, 36000)
            return jobs_count

    def get_electronics_count(self, region, city):
        logging.debug('attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region %s city %s'
                       % (str(region), str(city)))
        key = str(region) + 'electronicscount' + str(city)
        data = memcache.get(key)
        electronics_count = 0
        if data is not None:
            logging.debug('got data %s from memcache', str(data))
            return data
        else:
            if city and int(city) > 0:
                electronics_count_gql = \
                    db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Ad WHERE category IN ('5010', '5020', '5030', '5040') AND cities = KEY('City', :1) AND published = True AND modified > :2 "
                                , city, datetime.now()
                                - timedelta(days=609))
                electronics_count = electronics_count_gql.count(limit=40000)

            elif region and int(region) > 0:
                electronics_count_gql = \
                    db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Ad WHERE category IN ('5010', '5020', '5030', '5040') AND regions = KEY('Region', :1) AND published = True AND modified > :2 "
                                , int(region), datetime.now()
                                - timedelta(days=609))
                electronics_count = electronics_count_gql.count(limit=40000)
            memcache.add(key, electronics_count, 36000)
            return electronics_count

    def get_estate_count(self, region, city):
        logging.debug('attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region %s city %s'
                       % (str(region), str(city)))
        key = str(region) + 'estatecount' + str(city)
        data = memcache.get(key)
        estate_count = 0
        if data is not None:
            logging.debug('got data %s from memcache', str(data))
            return data
        else:
            if city and int(city) > 0:
                estate_count_gql = \
                    db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Ad WHERE category IN ('1010', '1020', '1030', '1050', '1080', '1090', '1100') AND cities = KEY('City', :1) AND published = True AND modified > :2 "
                                , city, datetime.now()
                                - timedelta(days=609))
                estate_count = estate_count_gql.count(limit=40000)

            elif region and int(region) > 0:
                estate_count_gql = \
                    db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Ad WHERE category IN ('1010', '1020', '1030', '1050', '1080', '1090', '1100') AND regions = KEY('Region', :1) AND published = True AND modified > :2 "
                                , int(region), datetime.now()
                                - timedelta(days=609))
                estate_count = estate_count_gql.count(limit=40000)
            memcache.add(key, estate_count, 36000)
            return estate_count


    def get_home_count(self, region, city):
        logging.debug('attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region %s city %s'
                       % (str(region), str(city)))
        key = str(region) + 'homecount' + str(city)
        data = memcache.get(key)
        home_count = None
        if data is not None:
            logging.debug('got data %s from memcache', str(data))
            return data
        else:
            if city and int(city) > 0:
                home_count_gql = \
                    db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Ad WHERE category IN ('3030', '3040', '3050', '3060') AND cities = KEY('City', :1) AND published = True AND modified > :2 "
                                , city, datetime.now()
                                - timedelta(days=609))
                home_count = home_count_gql.count(limit=40000)

            elif region and int(region) > 0:
                home_count_gql = \
                    db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Ad WHERE category IN ('3030', '3040', '3050', '3060') AND regions = KEY('Region', :1) AND published = True AND modified > :2 "
                                , int(region), datetime.now()
                                - timedelta(days=609))
                home_count = home_count_gql.count(limit=40000)
            memcache.add(key, home_count, 36000)
            return home_count

    def get_leisure_count(self, region, city):
        logging.debug('attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region %s city %s'
                       % (str(region), str(city)))
        key = str(region) + 'leisurecount' + str(city)
        data = memcache.get(key)
        leisure_count = None
        if data is not None:
            logging.debug('got data %s from memcache', str(data))
            return data
        else:
            if city and int(city) > 0:
                leisure_count_gql = \
                    db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Ad WHERE category IN ('4010', '4020', '4030', '4040', '4060', '4090') AND cities = KEY('City', :1) AND published = True AND modified > :2 "
                                , city, datetime.now()
                                - timedelta(days=609))
                leisure_count = leisure_count_gql.count(limit=40000)

            elif region and int(region) > 0:
                leisure_count_gql = \
                    db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Ad WHERE category IN ('4010', '4020', '4030', '4040', '4060', '4090') AND regions = KEY('Region', :1) AND published = True AND modified > :2 "
                                , int(region), datetime.now()
                                - timedelta(days=609))
                leisure_count = leisure_count_gql.count(limit=40000)
            memcache.add(key, leisure_count, 36000)
            return leisure_count

    def get_vehicles_count(self, region, city):
        logging.debug('attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region %s city %s'
                       % (str(region), str(city)))
        key = str(region) + 'vehiclescount' + str(city)
        data = memcache.get(key)
        vehicles_count = None
        if data is not None:
            logging.debug('got data %s from memcache', str(data))
            return data
        else:
            if city and int(city) > 0:
                vehicles_count_gql = \
                    db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Ad WHERE category IN ('2010', '2030', '2040', '2070', '2080') AND cities = KEY('City', :1) AND published = True AND modified > :2 "
                                , city, datetime.now()
                                - timedelta(days=609))
                vehicles_count = vehicles_count_gql.count(limit=40000)

            elif region and int(region) > 0:
                vehicles_count_gql = \
                    db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Ad WHERE category IN ('2010', '2030', '2040', '2070', '2080') AND regions = KEY('Region', :1) AND published = True AND modified > :2 "
                                , int(region), datetime.now()
                                - timedelta(days=609))
                vehicles_count = vehicles_count_gql.count(limit=40000)
            memcache.add(key, vehicles_count, 36000)
            return vehicles_count


    def get_jobs_count_india(self, region, city):
        logging.debug('attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region %s city %s'
                       % (str(region), str(city)))
        key = str(region) + 'jobscountindia' + str(city)
        data = memcache.get(key)
        jobs_count_gql = None
        if data is not None:
            logging.debug('got data %s from memcache', str(data))
            return data
        else:
            jobs_count_gql = \
                db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Ad WHERE category IN ('6010', '6020', '6030', '6040', '6090') AND published = True AND modified > :1 "
                            , datetime.now() - timedelta(days=609))
            jobs_count = jobs_count_gql.count(limit=40000)
            memcache.add(key, jobs_count, 36000)
            return jobs_count

    def get_electronics_count_india(self, region, city):
        logging.debug('attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region %s city %s'
                       % (str(region), str(city)))
        key = str(region) + 'electronicscountindia' + str(city)
        data = memcache.get(key)
        electronics_count_gql = None
        if data is not None:
            logging.debug('got data %s from memcache', str(data))
            return data
        else:
            electronics_count_gql = \
                db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Ad WHERE category IN ('5010', '5020', '5030', '5040') AND published = True AND modified > :1 "
                            , datetime.now() - timedelta(days=609))
            electronics_count = electronics_count_gql.count(limit=40000)
            memcache.add(key, electronics_count, 36000)
            return electronics_count


    def get_estate_count_india(self, region, city):
        logging.debug('attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region %s city %s'
                       % (str(region), str(city)))
        key = str(region) + 'estatecountindia' + str(city)
        data = memcache.get(key)
        estate_count_gql = None
        if data is not None:
            logging.debug('got data %s from memcache', str(data))
            return data
        else:
            estate_count_gql = \
                db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Ad WHERE category IN ('1010', '1020', '1030', '1050', '1080', '1090', '1100') AND published = True AND modified > :1 "
                            , datetime.now() - timedelta(days=609))
            estate_count = estate_count_gql.count(limit=40000)
            memcache.add(key, estate_count, 36000)
            return estate_count

    def get_home_count_india(self, region, city):
        logging.debug('attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region %s city %s'
                       % (str(region), str(city)))
        key = str(region) + 'homecountindia' + str(city)
        data = memcache.get(key)
        home_count_gql = None
        if data is not None:
            logging.debug('got data %s from memcache', str(data))
            return data
        else:
            home_count_gql = \
                db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Ad WHERE category IN ('3030', '3040', '3050', '3060') AND published = True AND modified > :1 "
                            , datetime.now() - timedelta(days=609))
            home_count = home_count_gql.count(limit=40000)
            memcache.add(key, home_count, 36000)
            return home_count

def get_leisure_count_india(self, region, city):
    logging.debug('attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region %s city %s'
                   % (str(region), str(city)))
    key = str(region) + 'leisurecountindia' + str(city)
    data = memcache.get(key)
    leisure_count_gql = None
    if data is not None:
        logging.debug('got data %s from memcache', str(data))
        return data
    else:
        leisure_count_gql = \
            db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Ad WHERE category IN ('4010', '4020', '4030', '4040', '4060', '4090') AND published = True AND modified > :1 "
                        , datetime.now() - timedelta(days=609))
        leisure_count = leisure_count_gql.count(limit=40000)
        memcache.add(key, leisure_count, 36000)
        return leisure_count

def get_vehicles_count_india(self, region, city):
    logging.debug('attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region %s city %s'
                   % (str(region), str(city)))
    key = str(region) + 'vehiclescountindia' + str(city)
    data = memcache.get(key)
    vehicles_count_gql = None
    if data is not None:
        logging.debug('got data %s from memcache', str(data))
        return data
    else:
        vehicles_count_gql = \
            db.GqlQuery("SELECT * FROM Ad WHERE category IN ('2010', '2030', '2040', '2070', '2080') AND published = True AND modified > :1 "
                        , datetime.now() - timedelta(days=609))
        vehicles_count = vehicles_count_gql.count(limit=40000)
        memcache.add(key, vehicles_count, 36000)
        return vehicles_count

def find_documents(query_string, limit, cursor):
    try:
        date_desc = search.SortExpression(expression='date',
                direction=search.SortExpression.DESCENDING,
                default_value=datetime(1999,01,01))

        hr_desc = search.SortExpression(expression='hour',
                direction=search.SortExpression.DESCENDING,
                default_value=1)

        min_desc = search.SortExpression(expression='minute',
                direction=search.SortExpression.DESCENDING,
                default_value=1)

        # Sort up to  matching results by subject in descending order
        sort = search.SortOptions(expressions=[date_desc, hr_desc,
                                  min_desc], limit=ACCURACY)

        # Set query options
        options = search.QueryOptions(limit=50, cursor=cursor,
                sort_options=sort,
                number_found_accuracy=10000,
              #  returned_fields=['title', 'city', 'region','category', 'adID', 'date','price', 'type', 'company_ad', 'adID', 'cityID','regionID', 'hour','minute'],
             #snippeted_fields=['text']
              )
        query = search.Query(query_string=query_string, options=options)
        index = search.Index(name=_INDEX_NAME)
        logging.debug('query_string i find %s' , str(query.query_string))
        logging.debug('query_options i find %s' , str(query.options))
        # Execute the query
        return index.search(query)

    except search.PutError as e:
        logging.exception('caught PutError %s', e)

    except search.InternalError as e:
        logging.exception('caught InternalError %s', e)

    except search.DeleteError as e:
        logging.exception('caught DeleteError %s', e)

    except search.TransientError as e:
        logging.exception('caught TransientError %s', e)

    except search.InvalidRequest as e:
        logging.exception('caught InvalidError %s', e)

    except search.Error as e:
        logging.exception('caught unknown error  %s', e)

    return None

def mutate_query(self, query):

    # query = query.replace(...) # whatever you are doing here

    query = re.sub("regionID=\d+", '', query)
    to_remove = [
        'category and',
        'type=s',
        'type=w',
        'type=r',
        'type=b',
        'cityID and',
        'and',
        'regionID',
        ]
    for s in to_remove:
        query = query.replace(s, '')
    query = query.replace('=', '%3D')
    query = re.sub("cityID%3D\d+", '', query)
    query = re.sub("category%3D\d+", '', query)
    query = query.replace('  ', ' ')
    return query
```

I added more logging to the code and updated:

```
class India(SearchBaseHandler):

    def get_data(self, key, query):
        data = memcache.get(key)
        if data is not None:
            logging.info('got India data from memcache')
            return data
        else:
            data = find_documents(query, 50, search.Cursor())
            memcache.add(key, data, 36000)
            return data

    def get_count(self, key):
        data = memcache.get(key)
        if data is not None:
            return data
        else:
            data = Ad.all().filter('published =',
                                   True).filter('modified >',
                    datetime.datetime.now()
                    - timedelta(days=609)).count(limit=40000)
            memcache.add(key, data, 36000)
            return data

    def get(self):
        """Handles a get request with a query."""
        regionname = None
        logging.info('get India data')
        country = 'India'
        cursor = self.request.get('cursor')
        region = None
        if self.request.host.find('hipheap') > -1: country = 'USA'
        elif self.request.host.find('koolbusiness') > -1: country = 'India'
        elif self.request.host.find('montao') > -1: country = 'Brasil'
        uri = urlparse(self.request.uri)
        #query = self.request.GET['query']

        query = ''
        if uri.query:
            query = parse_qs(uri.query)
            try:
                query = query['query'][0]
            except KeyError, err:
                query = ''

        key = 'india-adlist'
        results=None
        logging.info('trying to get cached data')
        if cursor:
            logging.info('round-trip with cursor')
            results = find_documents(query, 50, search.Cursor(cursor))
        else:
            results = self.get_data( key, query )
            logging.info('got cached data')

        next_cursor = None
        if results and results.cursor: next_cursor = results.cursor.web_safe_string
        query = query.replace(' and company_ad=0', ''
                              ).replace(' and company_ad=1', '')
        regionname = 'Entire India'
        regionID = 0
        cityID = 0
        form = SearchForm()
        form.w.choices = region_id_to_name
        n_res = self.get_count('count_koolbusiness')
        logging.debug('setting template values')
        template_values = {
            'number_found':n_res,
            'regions':region_id_to_name,
            'form': form,
            'results': results,
            'cursor': next_cursor,
            'region': region,
            'country': country,
            'number_returned': len(results.results),
            'jobs_count': get_jobs_count_india(self, regionID, cityID),
            'estate_count': get_estate_count_india(self, regionID,
                    cityID),
            'electronics_count': get_electronics_count_india(self,
                    regionID, cityID),
            'home_count': get_home_count_india(self, regionID, cityID),
            'leisure_count': get_leisure_count_india(self, regionID,
                    cityID),
            'vehicles_count': get_vehicles_count_india(self, regionID,
                    cityID),
            'user': users.get_current_user(),
            'loggedin': self.logged_in,
            'region': region,
            'regionname': regionname,
            'city': '',
            'cityentity': None,
            'request': self.request,
            'form': SearchForm(),
            'query': query,
            }
        logging.debug('rendering template')
        self.render_template('q.htm', template_values)
```

The log then becoindicates that it the the template rendering that is slow i.e. the last line of the code `self.render_template`

```
2013-12-24 15:26:31.490 /india 200 13508ms 16kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36 module=default version=2014c
I 2013-12-24 15:26:18.148 get India data
I 2013-12-24 15:26:18.148 trying to get cached data
I 2013-12-24 15:26:18.155 got India data from memcache
I 2013-12-24 15:26:18.156 got cached data
D 2013-12-24 15:26:18.158 setting template values
D 2013-12-24 15:26:18.158 attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region 0 city 0
D 2013-12-24 15:26:18.160 get_jobs_count_india data 10381 from memcache
D 2013-12-24 15:26:18.160 attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region 0 city 0
D 2013-12-24 15:26:18.163 get_estate_count_india data 930 from memcache
D 2013-12-24 15:26:18.163 attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region 0 city 0
D 2013-12-24 15:26:18.164 get_electronics_count_india data 817 from memcache
D 2013-12-24 15:26:18.165 attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region 0 city 0
D 2013-12-24 15:26:18.167 get_home_count_india data 455 from memcache
D 2013-12-24 15:26:18.167 attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region 0 city 0
D 2013-12-24 15:26:18.169 get_leisure_count_india data 137 from memcache
D 2013-12-24 15:26:18.169 attempting to fetch data from memchcache for region 0 city 0
D 2013-12-24 15:26:18.171 get_vehicles_count_india data 175 from memcache
D 2013-12-24 15:26:18.172 rendering template
```

[image]

Looking with appstats it looks like there are still roundtrips at the page `/india` but I didn't find where.

[image]

Now I also get I message from appstats in the log:

```
2013-12-24 15:45:07.315 /india 200 16962ms 16kb Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/31.0.1650.63 Safari/537.36 module=default version=2014c
D 2013-12-24 15:44:50.487 rendering template
D 2013-12-24 15:45:07.128 done rendering template
I 2013-12-24 15:45:07.169 Full proto too large to save, cleared variables.
I 2013-12-24 15:45:07.181 Saved; key: __appstats__:090400, part: 120 bytes, full: 217081 bytes, overhead: 0.114 + 0.052; link: http://www.koolbusiness.com/_ah/stats/details?tim
```

Comment: any reasons why you don't just use `query = self.request.GET['query']`?

Comment: @LieRyan If I use `query = self.request.GET['query']` I get a `KeyError: 'query'`. I suppose I must do it like in the code that doesn't return that KeyError, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: I would profile with appstats.  Some of these queries look expensive and some may not hang around in memcache.  What sort of cache hit ratio are you getting ?  I suggest you also perform logging to identify where time is spent in your handler.

Comment: @TimHoffman Thank you for the comment. I got 58 % hitrate in memcache and I'm updating the question with more logging around setting all the values to the template and then I can profile with appstats.

Comment: Is `query` optional? Then you can just use `query = self.request.GET.get('query', '')`. If `query` is missing from the query string, then it'll be replaced with the empty string.

Comment: My apps typically see hit rate of 85-95%.  Down at 58% nearly half your requests to memcache are not being met.  memcache tends to have a LRU behaviour , so if you are caching things that are not likely to be retrieved again with in a few minutes you are probably wasting your time. If the results of these queries do not change from minute to minute and they are sparse (not frequently used - e,g result for each city,) you may want to preprocess these queries and store the result in a datastore record or two instead, and just fetch the result by key.

Comment: @TimHoffman I looked with Appstats and there seemed to be datastore operations going on but I don't know which. This is my first use with appstats and when I try to profile I think it looks like appstats reports roundtrips to the datastore?

Comment: Your helper functions could really use some refactoring. Moving the code that stores and retrieves results from memcache to a decorator could reduce some of the duplications in the helper functions.

Comment: I would add some logging after self.render_template you have no visibility on how long that call takes.

Comment: In addition to refactorying you may find that a lot of these queries could be performed as Ad's are added rather than at view time, then store the results of the queries.  Thats a lot more refactoring of course, so find out first where you time is being spent.

Comment: Ok, I thought self.render_template was the last line that could be reached but I can try to add logging after. Appstats reports something that looks like datastore operations: `datastore_v3.Get 86 0 datastore_v3.RunQuery 86` does that mean that there are roundtrips to the datastore somewhere in my functions?

Comment: You can drill down further into appstats and see more detail for an individual request.  I want to see how long you template takes to render though.

Comment: @TimHoffman When rendering the template I get in the log `Full proto too large to save, cleared variables` which updated the original question with. It seems that the rendering takes time but also that there are datastore operations.

Comment: You need to start logging the various part of what is going on in the template.  You have already called most of your helpers before you render the template and all the time is being lost during the template render.  Maybe you have some really inefficient code in the template or your trying to do too much there.

Comment: Also the number of rpcs and the time for them is small as shown in appstats, so that doesn't appear to be where the time is being spent.  Focus on the template rendering and what is going on there for the moment.

Comment: As Tim said, it seems the slow part seems to be in the rendering of the template. django-debug-toolbar template-timings 3rd party panel might come in handy here.

Comment: Thanks. You must be right since I switched the template to an empty template and then it was fast. The template does a for loop with 50 items, I will try and render only that loop to see if that is the critical part.

Comment: @TimHoffman I found that it is my `get_serving_url`that takes time in the loop so I can either choose not to display thumbnail or cache the url from `get_serving_url`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

memcache isn't the guilty party here. If you look at the time in the log, all of the memcache calls are finished within the first second upon receiving the request. It's likely what's slow is the rest of the request. The various calls to get_jobs/estate/electronics/home/leisure/vehicles_count_india looks suspect, the template rendering could also be slow if you have a very large number of variables such as when you have a very large search result and you don't paginate.

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting. I added the helper functions to the question. I don't see where the large latency is spent since like you say it is reported in the log that is is fast. There could be a bug in one of the helper functions but I don't see it and I'm running out of ideas why the page with the list is so much slower than the simpler page. The simpler page is very fast but the list page is too slow. I display 50 items per page.

Comment: @909Niklas: you can use django-debug-toolbar to help find slow database queries, among other things it can do. Also, try adding some logging to the helper functions, the time recorded in the log could help you figure out which one is taking so much time.

Comment: Also, sprinkle some logging before and after calculating the context data, i.e. before `template_values = {...}` and before `self.render_template(...)`, what are their times?

Comment: I put logging before and after template rendering and I got an error message in the log that my data might be too large? I updated the question with the reports from appstats and logging for the instructions. The page still loads slow and from what I can profile it looks like there are datastore operations but I can't find where they are and I don't know what it means with `Full proto too large to save, cleared variables` ?

Comment: Info about the warning message from appstat "Full proto too large to save, cleared variables": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10169574/full-proto-too-large-to-save-cleared-variables. It's harmless, except that the debugging data shown in appstat may be incomplete.

Comment: It seems to be the place in the code where I make thumbnails from `get_serving_url`that takes a long time. It's a template loop that is supposed to make an image thumbnail for the items. `images.get_serving_url(str(self.matched_images.get().primary_image.key()), 80)` I don't know if it's the actual call to `get_serving_url`that is slow or if it is getting the entity which is done from memcache?